# Windows 7: automatic file extensions

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-extension

I have two accounts A and B on the same windows 7 machine. I log into account A and open a program (this happens in multiple programs, not only 1 specific program). I click on "save as" and choose "01.01.2017" as filename. The resulting file is of type "2017" since no .txt is appended. I do the exact same thing in account B and windows appends the .txt file ending. Where is the setting that is responsible for this different behaviour? I prefer the behaviour of account B.

Answer (score 0):

Start Windows Explorer, you can do this by opening up any folder.
Click Organize.
Click Folder and search options.
Click the View tab.
Scroll down until you notice Hide extensions for known file types, check this line by clicking the check box.
Click OK

Alternatively, you can type in the extension manually if you want file extensions visible. e.g. 01.01.2017.txt

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my question is not how to hide or not hide file extensions. I know about that. My question is why file extensions are appended in account B but not in account A.

Comment: When you are unable to view file extensions, the system automatically appends the file extension...which is what you are seeing as the problem. Try my solution...it works.